# Expression Designer Grid Item animations

Tags: grid, expression

I was curious if there is a way to animate moving an item in a Grid (in Expression) from one cell to another.

I know that I can change the Row and Column for an item in the Grid, but that just makes the items appear in the new location.  What I would like to do is when the Row or Column for the item changes, have the item smoothly move to the new location in the Grid (possibly with a transition effect like elasticity).

Thank you for you time.
Paul